# When do we prefer Laplace signal form instead of time signal form - Control Engineering

Tags: control-system, laplace-transform

I am struggling to see when you will prefer laplace transform X(s) instead of a time domain signal x(t).

- What does Laplace transform tell you?
- What is the benefits to use Laplace transform?
- What data can you get out of laplace transform?

Please use examples to show this.

Comment: Have you studied pole-zero diagrams (the fundamental reasoning behind analogue filters)?

Comment: Yes i have. This is where you can see where the poles and zeros are, when you set the laplace transform den(s)=0 or num(s)=0.

Comment: Smells like a homework / assignment question.

Comment: Not really. I am asking because i am confused about this. If the only comment you want to make is: "homework", then just dont comment on this. 

I am trying to get better, and people like you, is just doing it 10 times harder..

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a Laplace transform analysing a circuit in the time domain inevitable leads to integrals, derivates and ultimately differential equations, unless you restrict yourself to AC circuit analysis (pure sine wave signals) were the complex domain is an alternative to the Laplace transform. In the Laplace domain these differential equations become algebraic equations, in other words multiplications and divisions and therefore a lot easier to solve.

The final result after re-transformation is the same.

Comment: Thanks! So the  main reason to use Laplace transform is to solve the diff. eq. easier? What about the S-domain, which is the complex variable s in the laplace transform? What does it tell you? That you are operating in a complex plane? And that you can find out how the signal is behaving? (By finding the zeroes and poles)